# How to add empty object to existing object in jq

Tags: json, jq

I have this input.

```json
{
  "ver" : "2.4",
  "startDate"  : "2022-12-07T10:38:10+07:00",
  "disk" : {},
  "network" : {
    "ipv4" : {},
    "ipv6" : {}
  },
  "test" : {}
}
```

I want to add empty object `/dev/sda` for example into `disk`. Below is ideal output.

```json
{
    "ver": "2.4",
    "startDate": "2022-12-07T10:38:10+07:00",
    "disk": {
        "/dev/sda": {}
    },
    "network": {
        "ipv4": {},
        "ipv6": {}
    },
    "test": {}
}
```

I search the net but only found how to add element, not how to add empty object.

Comment: Just `jq '.disk."/dev/sda" = {}'` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B8Wy2wT1CN8)

Comment: @pmf thanks, you should post it as answer. I spent 30 min looking on the net and documentation and did not found it.

Comment: @pmf I cannot do this with shell variable, it doesn't expand: `jq --arg dvn $devname '.disk_bench."$dvn" = {}' filename` where `devname` is /dev/sdb. The result is still with dollar sign &rarr; `"$dvn": {}`

Comment: @Liso You need to do `.disk_bench[$dvn] = {}`

Comment: @Liso Or use string interpolation: `jq --arg dvn "$devname" '.disk_bench."\($dvn)" = {}'`